# Hive- Create table only if first table is empty

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to write query in `hive`, where I need to join `tableA` with `TableB` on `col1`, if there is a match then processing completes. But if we don't get any matching records then we need to perform different join criteria on `col2`.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

I need something like this:

```sql
create table Data1 AS
select *
from table1
join table2
  on table1.a = table2.a;
```

- I want to check if the first table is empty or not, if it is not empty, then only create second one.
- I don't know how to check if first table has data in it

```sql
create table Data2 AS
select *
from table1
join table2
  on table1.b = table2.b;
```

----------Example 2nd Join -----------------

```
with tableA as (
select 1 as a,  22 as b 
union
select 2 as a,  23 as b 
union
select 3 as a,  2 as b 
)
,
tableB as (
select 111 as a,  2 as b 
union
select 222 as a,  1 as b 
)
select x.* from 
tableA x join tableB y
on x.b=y.b
```

so it should answer 3,2,which uses second join, as we dont have matching records for first one.

----------First Join

```
with tableA as (
select 1 as a,  22 as b 
union
select 2 as a,  23 as b 
union
select 3 as a,  2 as b 
)
,
tableB as (
select 1 as a,  2 as b 
union
select 2 as a,  1 as b 
)
select x.* from 
tableA x join tableB y
on x.a=y.a
```

it should give below result:

```
a   b
1   22
2   23
```

as first join works,we shouldnt get any records matching with second join condition.

***** sorry I have used example data from SQL server and not hive

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you update your question with the queries you already tried? Showing effort in trying to solve your own problem greatly motivates (and helps!) the community to solve the problem *together* with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Thanks for your help.I got solution for my problem:

First I performed joins in two different tables,and then used Except operator for required results.Its working!

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST3
            CREATE TABLE TEST3 AS 
            SELECT * from
            (
            SELECT * FROM TEST1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT * FROM TEST2 a
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM TEST3 b WHERE a.UNQKEY=b.UNQKEY)
            )a
```

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out Hive doesn't support `or` in the join clause, but now that I think about it this isn't quite what you want anyway. To exactly replicate your business logic, you can use the following code, which uses a left join for each of your conditions and then a case statement

```
select t1_a, t1_b, --repeat for all cols of table1
case when t1_a is not null then t1_a else B.a end,
case when t1_b is not null then t1_b else B.b end
--repeat this for all the columns of table2    
 from   
    (select table1.a t1_a, table1.b t1_b --repeat for all cols of table1
            ,table2.a t2_a, table2.b t2_b --repeat for all cols of table2
    from table1
    left join table2 
      on table1.a = A.a) A
    left join 
     table2 B
      on (t2_a is null and t1_b = B.b);
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.Unfortunately hive doesnt support OR cluase in join.

Comment: huh didn't know that, i'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: Thanks!But what I think it will select all records from joining criteria 2, even if we are getting records from join1

Comment: have you tested it? i don't think this will happen, very last line says "only join on the second criteria if t2_a is null, i.e., if we haven't found any matches for the first criteria

Comment: I tested with below query:

Comment: with tableA as (select 1 as a,  22 as b 
union
select 2 as a,  23 as b 
union
select 3 as a,  2 as b 
)
,tableB as (select 1 as a,  2 as b 
union
select 2 as a,  1 as b)
select t1_a,t1_b, 
case when t1_a is not null then t1_a else b.a end,
case when t1_b is not null then t1_b else b.b end,
t2_a,t2_b
 from   
    (select tableA.a as t1_a, tableA.b as t1_b 
            ,tableB.a as t2_a, tableB.b as t2_b
    from tableA 
    left join tableB  
      on tableA.a = tableB.a) A
    left join 
     tableB B
      on (t2_a is null and t1_b = B.b)